# gatsby-ssr.js doesn't seem to be running

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

At a loss, I have two borderline identical projects using the same method to wrap the app in a provider. One works and one doesn't.

After a lot of troubleshooting, seems like `gatsby-ssr.js` is simply not being run for some reason.

I've added the following to `gatsby-ssr.js & gatsby-browser.js`. Nothing is getting logged, so I know this is never being run. Adding the same export to my other project logs the store, so I know there is something wrong here.

```
    export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
    console.log(store);
    return <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>;
};
```

The broken project is running Gatsby 4.19.2
The working project is running Gatsby 2.21.1

However, I have tried downgrading and still seem to be experiencing the same issue. I've deleted cache, re-installed all packages, have tried different versions.  Not sure if anyone is familiar with potential edge cases or differences in gatsby versions in how `gatsby-ssr.js` gets executed?

Update:

Added

```
export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  console.log('ReactDOM.render has executed');
};
```

to both files and still nothing.

Comment: Is there any error prompted?

Comment: @FerranBuireu No, but appears there is a flag `DEV_SSR` that needs to be added to gatsby-config.js and it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SSR (`gatsby-ssr.js`) only applies when the site is built (`gatsby build`) unless you add a flag into your `gatsby-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // your existing config
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: true,
  },
}
```

*Note: all flags ant its descriptions available at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/src/utils/flags.ts*

*Note 2: flags are available from v2.28 onwards. Further reference https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v2.28/*

You should try it using either the `DEV_SSR` (easiest and fastest way) flag or using `gatsby build && gatsby serve`